# Vue + Font awesome SVG sometimes renders icons twice and gives JS error

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome

Here's a strange issue with Font Awesome 5 icons (SVG version) in a Vue app. I've replicated this in a new minimal Vue app:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/9xf0bim26lzsp7x/hello-world.tgz?dl=0

which can be run locally with `npm run serve' and accessed at
http://localhost:8080/#/detail/123

A view has a font awesome icon and some markup:

```
<template>
    <div>

        <div class="text-center">
            item.id {{item.id}}
            <p v-if="item.status == 'New'">Please confirm your appointment:</p>
            <!-- class="fas fa-user"  not useful. Sometimes icons are mess up. -->
            <p>{{item.practitioner_name}}</p>

            <p><i class="fas fa-map-marked-alt"></i> <a
                    :href="item.address_map_href"
                    target="_blank"
                >{{item.address.address1}} </a>
                <span v-if="item.address.address2">; </span>
                {{item.address.address2}}
            </p>

            <p>
                {{item.day}}<br>
            </p>

            <div v-if="item.status == 'New'">
                <button
                    variant="primary"
                    @click="itemConfirm()"
                    class="w-md"
                ><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Confirm</button>
                <br><br>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</template>

<script>


export default {
    props: ['id'],
    components: {
    },
    data: () => ({
        item: {
            address: {} //avoid error on render
        }
    }),

    async mounted() {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log("sadf")
        if (this.id && this.id != '0') {

            this.item = {
                "id": "mkt7y3v0m5vupnal",
                "practitioner_id": "yyie5csyc0y1lwcg",
                "day": "2019-11-08",
                "start_time": "16:00",
                "end_time": "16:45",
                "status": "New",
                "practitioner_name": "Dr",
                address: {}
            }
        }

    },

    methods: {

        itemConfirm() {

            this.item.status = 'Confirmed'

        },

    }

}

</script>
```

The result after clicking Confirm:

[image]

Observations

- The svg markup appears twice in DOM (see browser inspector in screenshot)
- Font Awesome js is loaded in index.html with
  `<script defer src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/mykit.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`
- Removing Font Awesome solves both the duplicate markup display and JS error

What would be the solution to continue using Font Awesome?

JS error:

> vue.esm.js?a026:628 [Vue warn]: Error in nextTick: "NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node."
>
> itemConfirm @ RecordDetail.vue?f97b:145
>
> click @ RecordDetail.vue?e784:50
>
> invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.esm.js?a026:1863
>
> invoker @ vue.esm.js?a026:2184
>
> original._wrapper @ vue.esm.js?a026:7559
>
> vue.esm.js?a026:1897 DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.

There's no nextTick() function in my code. I do NOT use v-for (saw this as another cause).

Comment: Can you post the complete markup / render of your Vue HTML as well as the codes you used to supplement that rendering?

Comment: Post the full Vue component. looks like a template error to me. You might be looping over empty data and that's why you see two sets of icons?

Comment: I noticed that you have commented out the `status` property in your `item.data` variable. This is the reason why the line of code `v-if="item.status == 'New'"` errors out. Can you remove the comment on that property and see how it goes. As I see it, you are dealing with multiple errors, which should be resolved first.

Comment: Thanks @Angelo, I already tried that, it has no effect, that's why I commented it. ```status``` is present as a property on the data loaded from server.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there’s a known issue with Font Awesome SVG and Vue. Instead of using the js bundle, they recommend the vue-fontawesome plugin, or use CSS bundle. It was quite hard to find that out, though, as the behavior is weird.